# Similar Shapes Problem

Tags: geometry

[image]

ABCD is a square with BE = 2EC
Express the following ratio in simplified form:

Area of Region 1 : Area of Region 2 : Area of Region 3 : Area of Region 4

NOTE: What I've found so far is 9 : ? : 1 : 3. I am unsure how to find the relation to 2, or whether or not my answers are correct thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose w.l.o.g. that $AB=1$ and define $DE\cap AC=\{F\}$.

Let $h_{AD}$ be the altitude of $AD$ in $\triangle DFA$ and $h_{EC}$ be the altitude of $EC$ in $\triangle EFC$. Observe now that

\begin{cases}h_{AD}+h_{EC}=1\\h_{AD}=3\cdot h_{EC}\end{cases} Which implies that $$h_{AD}=\frac34\qquad h_{EC}=\frac14$$

Therefore $$\text{Area}_1=\frac{1\cdot \frac34}2=\frac38\implies\begin{cases}\text{Area}_4=\frac12-\text{Area}_1=\frac18\\\text{Area}_3=\big(\frac13\big)^2\cdot \text{Area}_1=\frac{3}{72}\\\text{Area}_2=1-\big(\text{Area}_1+\text{Area}_3+\text{Area}_4\big)=\ldots\end{cases}$$

Can you end it now?

---

*Alternatively* (and perhaps simpler). Observe that $\triangle DFA\sim\triangle EFC$. Therefore $$AF=3\cdot FC\implies \frac{\text{Area}_1}{\text{Area}_4}=\frac{3}{1}\implies \text{Area}_1=\frac38\qquad \text{Area}_4=\frac18$$ Proceed then similarly as in the first proof...